# android : from a modern Android system, how to install an old apk only compatible to an older Android system

Tags: android, apk-tools

android :
from a modern Android system, how to install an old apk only compatible to an older Android system?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belong to https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not at all; when Android releases break compatibility, *they break compatibility*. The APIs that your old software uses are not there any more, with a relatively high chance; really old Apps tended to use private APIs for which Android made no promises on forward compatibility.

The software you want to install simply has a very high chance of not working anymore; investing time trying to get it to run without being the author of the code (or at least knowing well it's not going to attempt to use APIs not present anymore) is probably not wise.

Technically, Android 11/API level 30 (and on) has changed the signature algorithm: If you have an old APK, it won't be installable without being signed with the new algorithm. You *can* do that (if the rest of the software *was* compatible, which, again, chances are it isn't), but you'll have to be familiar with the Android APK packaging & signing, sideloading and installing procedure. You will have to enable developer access on your phone, which isn't possible on all phones, and on some might require you getting a key from the phone manufacturer.

Good luck!

Comment: What do you think about a LXC solution ? An Android apk that virtualizes an older Android ABI? I think old apk, most of all, use only a minimal part of older system. It could be abusive that older apk cannot be used because of a nothing...

Comment: completely different question. If you can emulate an old android, you can install old software. Don't know what LXC brings to the table here beyond Linux containers – that's like a really really really tiny part of what needs to be done to emulate an android environment.